# how to get image which is in imageview at runtime and compare it to other stored image?

Tags: android, android-imageview

I already stored images into array **(int image[0][0]=R.Drawable.img1 like this).** I want to **compare the image[0][0] with which image is in the imageview.**

I want to know which image is in the imageview if i click the imageview, the image will be change. so **i need to know which image is in imageview?**

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using the tag of the `ImageView` for this.

Whenever you set the `ImageView`'s image, also set the tag, and then later check the tag to see what's the image.

```
image.setImageResource(R.drawable.pic1);
image.setTag(R.drawable.pic1);

...

long id = (long) image.getTag();
if (id == R.drawable.pic1) {
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can store the id of the current drawable using [View.setTag()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setTag%28java.lang.Object%29). Later you can retrieve by [View.getTag()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getTag%28%29) and compare it with the values stored in your array.